# VBA code to Dynamically reordering the columns based on items selected in listbox

Tags: vba

am very new to VBA, my question is-
How to reorder columns based on user’s selection in the listbox? or is there any other userforms to do this??

There are 8 text columns and 12 months column (Total 20 cols)

I got a listbox1 prepared to get the columns which are selected from listbox1  along with 12 months columns, then subtotaling based on column A. This code populate columns based on the listbox1 index number,

But i really need columns to get rearranged based on the user selected in listbox1.

Suppose – If user selects 4th column first and 1st column second, i need the similar way the columns should be arranged –

Any help will be really appreciated, only this part troubling me to completed the project.
Thanks for the help!!
Raghu

below is the code which am currently using  -

---

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

'Variable Declaration

Dim iCnt As Integer, i As Long, j As Long, shdr As String

Dim MyHdr() As String, cols(12) As Long

Dim count As Integer, lastRow As Integer, destCol As Integer
count = 0

destCol = 1
For iCnt = 0 To Me.ListBox1.ListCount - 1

If Me.ListBox1.Selected(iCnt) = True Then

ReDim Preserve MyHdr(count)

MyHdr(count) = ListBox1.List(iCnt)

count = count + 1

End If

Next iCnt
If count = 0 Then

MsgBox "Please Select One Or More Items Then Try Again!", vbExclamation

Exit Sub

End If
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

With Sheet2.Range("A16:Z10000")

On Error Resume Next

.RemoveSubtotal

On Error GoTo ErrHandler
.ColumnWidth = 9

.Clear

End With
'Find Last Row In Sheet1

lastRow = Sheet1.Cells.SpecialCells(xlLastCell).Row
For i = LBound(MyHdr) To UBound(MyHdr)

shdr = MyHdr(i)

For j = 1 To 8

If Sheet1.Cells(1, j) = shdr Then

Sheet1.Range(Sheet1.Cells(1, j), Sheet1.Cells(lastRow, j)).Copy Destination:=Sheet2.Cells(16, destCol)

destCol = destCol + 1

Exit For

End If

Next j

Next i
'Copy Month Data

Sheet1.Range(Sheet1.Cells(1, 9), Sheet1.Cells(lastRow, 20)).Copy Destination:=Sheet2.Cells(16, destCol)
Sheet2.Range("A16:T100000").Sort _
Key1:=Range("A1"), Header:=xlYes
 Columns("A").ColumnWidth = 25

'Add Column Totals

destCol = destCol + 12
With Sheet2

.Cells(16, destCol).Value = "Grand Total"

.Cells(16, destCol).ColumnWidth = 13

.Range("A16").Copy

.Cells(16, destCol).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
.Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(1, destCol - 1)).ColumnWidth = 11

.Range(.Cells(17, destCol), .Cells(lastRow + 15, destCol)).FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(RC2:RC[-1])"
'Add Subtotals

For i = 0 To 12

cols(i) = destCol - 12 + i

Next i
.Cells(16, 1).Subtotal GroupBy:=1, Function:=xlSum, TotalList:=cols, Replace:=True, PageBreaks:=False, SummaryBelowData:=True
.Outline.ShowLevels RowLevels:=2

Sheet1.Activate: .Activate

End With
ExitHandler:

Unload Me

Application.CutCopyMode = False

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Exit Sub
ErrHandler:

MsgBox Err.Description, vbExclamation

Resume ExitHandler

End Sub
```

---

The above code is working well, but i couldnt able to get the text columns reorder the way user is selecting in listbox1, whichever column header user selected that column should get pasted first and then keep follow the selected pattern until the user selecting completes,

Eg : Table may start - Col (5,1,3) or Col (8,5,2,6,1,7,3,4), whichever order they select same order the columns should get pasted.

Answer (score 0):

declare `MyHdr()` and `count()` as userform scoped variables, and then have `ListBox1_Change()` event handler update them

as follows

```
Option Explicit

Dim MyHdr() As String '<--| place it at the very top of your userform code pane to become userform scoped variable
Dim count As Integer '<--| place it at the very top of your userform code pane to become userform scoped variable

Private Sub ListBox1_Change()
    Dim iCnt As Integer, iArr As Integer

    With Me.ListBox1
        If .Selected(.ListIndex) Then '<--| if item selected then add it to 'Hydr()'
            count = count + 1 '<--| update counter
            ReDim Preserve MyHdr(count - 1)
            MyHdr(count - 1) = .List(.ListIndex)
        Else '<--| if item selected then remove it to 'Hydr()'
            For iCnt = 0 To UBound(MyHdr) '<--| loop through 'Hydr()' and find its position
                If MyHdr(iCnt) = .List(.ListIndex) Then '<--| once found
                    For iArr = iCnt + 1 To UBound(MyHdr) '<-- swap back 'Hydr()' elements and erase the deselected one
                        MyHdr(iArr - 1) = MyHdr(iArr)
                    Next
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next iCnt
            count = count - 1 '<--| update counter
            If count > 0 Then ReDim Preserve MyHdr(count - 1) '<--| resize 'Hydr()'
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

so that the first part of your `CommandButton1_Click()` becomes:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim Sheet1 As Worksheet, Sheet2 As Worksheet

    'Variable Declaration

    Dim iCnt As Integer, i As Long, j As Long, shdr As String
    Dim cols(12) As Long
    Dim count As Integer, lastRow As Integer, destCol As Integer

    count = 0

    If count = 0 Then
        MsgBox "Please Select One Or More Items Then Try Again!", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If
    destCol = 1    

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    ' here follows the rest of your sub
```

Comment: I used the above code but i dont see the columns are re-arranging based on the selection, below is the entire code -

Comment: i can even send you the sample workbook if required, please do let me know any email id or place where i can upload the macro workbook.

Comment: Subtotals leaves a large gap??

Comment: the last item and the grand total are about 3000 rows down from the last entry

Comment: I gave you the have `MyHdr()` array filled with listbox selected items in the order they have been selected by the user. Which is what you needed. I didn't go into the code that uses `MyHdr()` array which is another part you said _"it is working well"_ but for the user listbox selection order part. So split the problem: 1) check `Hydr()` properly filled 2) then check the 2nd part of the code. To "check" you can step through your code (pressing F8 to jump between statements to be executed) and querying relevant variable sin Immediate Window (e.g.: `?destCol` + press return, and the likes

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, am new bee for VBA , really apologies for that... can you please guide me on how to club these two codes into one and make the code working in the way we desired to be?? Thanks, raghu